# C# WinForm with local mdf Database on Client-PC

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, mdf

I have some problems at the moment with an Applicaion of mine. 
I got the task to create a Application for display stock data.
So i'd build a WinForm application with a local mdf Database. 
The Application works great on my developer machine.

For the clients i've got some restrictions because of security reasons: I'm not allowed to install anything on the Client PC.

So after a long time of trail and error the application now starts on client PC. But the database connection will not work (db is local on Client).
The reason is that there are no SQL connectors installed on clients.

My questions is if there is any possibility to use SQLExpress or anything else without install on client?
(At the moment: providerName = "System.Data.SqlClient")

For the database Entity reference I use Telerik OpenAccess.

Thank u.

Comment: Google for `localdb`.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work. You have to install localdb too before using on Client PC. And for this I need admin priveleges.

Comment: You don't have to install anything. Admin of that machine will do. From security perspective it's absolutely normal to do e.g. windows updates. LocalDB is Microsoft product. Just state what your software require it.

Comment: ok know what you mean. But our IT is really strict. So they don't want non-it employees writing there own software. But we need this application, so we do shadow-IT.

Comment: Then `mdf` is a wrong choice I am afraid. You could e.g. use `mdb` without need to install anything (`OleDb` is a part of .net framework). P.S.: it's funny to ask, but how do you install .net framework then?

Comment: haha yes 4.0 Client Profile.
I will try mdb. But i think it is really slow and I'm afraid that Telerik OpenAccess do not support OleDb.
Thank you